# MySQL replace UNION with LEFT JOIN IFNULL

Tags: mysql, performance, join, union

sorry for the Title but I couldn't find a better description for our problem.

We have a user table and a token table which both needs to be UNIONt into one table but for performance reason without a UNION ALL.

The table structure is as follows:

```
Table USER:
ID Username Password

Table TOKEN:
ID User_ID Token Token_Secret
```

What we need is now a union of both tables.

An user is always present, an user has in most cases 1 or more tokens (1:N). The resulting table should contain

```
ID Username Password
```

with all users (wether they have a token or not) and, if the user has a token, all tokens

So with a UNION the result would be

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE (SOME JOINS TO GET THE RIGHT USERS)
UNION ALL
SELECT Token as Username, Token_Secret AS Password FROM token WHERE (SOME JOINS TO GET THE RIGHT TOKENS)
```

What I've tried so far is to just do a RIGHT JOIN like

```
SELECT IFNULL(b.Token, a.Username, b.Token) ... FROM 
(SELECT * FROM user WHERE (SOME JOINS)) AS a
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM token WHERE (SOME JOINS)) AS b
ON 
b.User_ID = a.ID
```

But in this case, I'll get all users, which have either no token (so I get the Username, Password from the user table) OR just the Token from the token table.. But what I need is both! If a user has also a token, I would need the username, password and all tokens (renamed as username, password)

Is there any way to do that without an UNION? The problem with the UNION is the temptable in MySQL and the huge amount of users, which will force MySQL to write a temp table with at least more than 10.000 records

Comment: A temp table with 10,000 records is not very large.  If `union all` does what you want, then go that route.

Comment: The UNION takes in total more than 20 seconds, so that's definitely too long to stay with an UNION

Comment: are you sure that the problem is with an UNION query? or are (SOME JOINS) that make the query slower?

Comment: Does it work better with `UNION ALL`, so it doesn't try to remove duplicates?

Comment: As we're using MySQL 5.6 (as 5.7 has some UNION optimizations) UNION ALL doesn't make a difference in creating a temp table. As there are no duplicates UNION and UNION ALL doesn't make a difference, even not in performance. Every single query itself is nearly instant (1st query is around 0.18 sec, 2nd query is around 0.134 sec, the UNION ALL (cause of the temp table) consumes around 19.380 seconds)

Comment: could you post sample data of both tables (10 records per each) and expected result recordset please?

Comment: I've created a very basic fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19796c/3
The id isn't vital. What I need now is the same structure/result just without the UNION ALL to prevent the temp table

Comment: no, the result set you ask is exactly `UNION` nothing else. there is no place for any `IFNULL` so probably you need something else?

Comment: `UNION` is the wrong way to go !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.token) AS tokens
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN tokens t ON t.user_id = u.id
    GROUP BY u.id;
```

If you need id, user, token:

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_name,
       IFNULL(t.token, '(no token for this user)') as token
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN tokens t ON t.user_id = u.id
    ORDER BY user_name, token;
```

Comment: Hello Rick, thank you for your purpose but that query doesn't really give me the result set I need. The structure of the result isn't changeable. I need a id, username, password field structure. Concatenating the tokens doesn't give me the right structure. The table is later used by another tool which needs that table structure

Comment: I think that there is no real way to prevent the join. Your edit also misses the original password, if present